# Merging pen lines to create logo

Tags: adobe-illustrator, typography, logo

I have finally got my logo to where I want it in illustrator, and I want to preserve all of my pen lines and strokes but just make it one joined object, so that I can transform it and move it around. Any ideas? Please and Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to Group your logo, which you can do with Command+G or under Object > Group. That will keep all of the objects within the logo separate, but will still allow you to move it as one.

If you want to merge all of the overlapping objects in your logo into one, you can use the Pathfinder panel and click the Add to Shape Area icon. It's the first one in the panel.

Comment: I believe the second part of your answer is what OP wants, as simply grouping won't affect line widths.